# Profiling functions in python

Tags: python, django, profiling

I would like to know if there is anyway to profile only a function in a python script which does not have a main(). I have a script which will be called by another one. But i want to know the loopholes in it.

I first use the commmand
kernprof -l -v filename.py

and then 
python -m line_profiler filename.py.lprof

I have added @profile before the function.

Comment: There's several ways of profiling your code. I like [line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) as it gives detail for individual lines rather than the function as a whole. Then you just decorate the function you want to profile with `@profile`.

Comment: Yes i tried line_profiler but i am not getting the output for every line. Also does it work for scripts without main()?

Comment: It's always given line-by-line for me in any function I have decorated. In regards to the `main()` I'm not sure what you're asking; I guess yes?

Comment: Thanks. I am able to get the output only for the first 2 lines and then its a blank.

Comment: In that case it might be better to edit this question with the specific input function and how you're using `line_profiler` plus the data contained in the file it creates. Currently this is a very broad question.

Comment: Your edit doesn't include all of the information I suggested. Try `python kernprof.py -l -v my_script_name.py > profiler_results.txt` to redirect the output to a file.

Comment: You might take a look at [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771).